# Efficient way to produce many small recordings and connect it to database

Tags: sql, audio-recording

For a language course I need to record many sentences and words separately. 
Ideally I would click on a button next to the written sentence in my database (e.g. MS Access or MySQL) and record the sentence. Then go to the next sentence.

Is there a way to do it that simple?

Until now, I record the sentence one by one in audio software like Soundbooth and type in a name each time. Than I have to type these names (and paths) in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would create sound files for each recording and then store the reference to each sound file in the database instead of storing the actual file as a blob.

Is that what you are doing at the moment and you are asking how to revert to storing blobs?

The job will be arduous either way, but you'll have a more maintainable structure if you keep data records in the DB only and a reference to the file.

Comment: I agree, saving it in seperate sound files with reference in the database seems to be the best way. But this procedure means that I type 1000 names for 1000 sound files. And afterwards type in 1000 paths/names.
What I am looking for is a more efficient way to do this. As all the information is in the database (name of sentence should be name of soundfile), it seems a lot of double work.
Robert